# Classic 350 Engine turns off while turning the handle bar to the left

Tags: engine, electrical, motorcycle, royal-enfield, enfield-classic

Hi I have recently started to face this issue on classic 350. When I turn the Handlebar to the left all the lights are on but the engine turns off. What could be the possible reasons could anyone help me out. I have examined the wiring there are no burned wirses.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect a broken wire ie the conductor has broken and separates when turning left, but the insulation is still intact so you cannot see it.

One way to test is try connecting a spare length of wire between the ignition switch and the coil (or other component - you have to trace it to find it) and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue with my RE Thunderbird 350 and took it to a mechanic. Comes out, there was some fault in the electrical wiring of the bike due to which when bike's handle was turned to the extreme left or right, the bike restarted.

The mechanic checked the wires and reconnected a few after which the bike was up and running again.

**Tip:** If you are facing this issue frequently and are not near a mechanic, you can open the small boxes that connect the wires which lie behind your bike's headlamp, blow some air into them and close them again. Sometimes, dust also play role due to which the electrical issues occur.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my RE Classic 350. The issue is that the 12V starting coil supply gets grounded somehow as you turn your handle bar and shuts the supply to spark plugs resulting in engine shutting down. In my case ampere meter was the faulty unit that was causing the grounding problem. It was replaced with new ampere meter. RE is running smooth after that. Hope it helps!